# TileList component with multiline Label AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, label, multiline, tilelist

Is there a way to make TileList's items' label multiline without messing with its cell renderer ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation specifies that `TileList`'s default cell renderer, `ImageCell`, displays a single-line label. I've looked around but it can't be changed by a public method or property.

So to use multi-line labels you will probably need to make your own cell renderer (possibly extending the `ImageCell` or `CellRenderer` class).

Comment: Right now I'm doing it in sort of hacky way by putting a  '\n' newline in label, and that does the job, but I have to find the place in label where to put it (where the first line should end) and that's problematic for variable lengthes.

Comment: That is a way to do it, but yeah it's problematic, especially if the label values are supplied by the user. So yeah unless you're content with using "\n", the only way I can think of is making your own cell renderer.

Comment: thanks, just wanted to make sure there was no easier alternative